# AWS: Identify Root User - Non Management Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

With an IAM user that has `AdministratorAccess` role, how do I identify who is the root user of the AWS account? BTW, the account is part of AWS Organizations and I do NOT have access to the management account.

Comment: The root user of an account is always called "Root user" in IAM.